# Swift 'defer' keyword causes Segmentation Fault

Tags: ios, swift, deferred

This is occurring on an entirely new Xcode project. The first class I added is a subclass of `UIView`, which works fine like this:

```
class CIHomeView: UIView {
init() {
    super.init(frame: CGRectZero)
    print("test")
}
```

However, as soon as I add the defer:

```
class CIHomeView: UIView {
init() {
    defer { super.init(frame: CGRectZero) }
    print("abc")
}
```

I get a segmentation fault compile error. Further, Xcode's syntax highlighting stops working momentarily. Very strange. My understanding is that defer is available as of Swift 2.0, and I am indeed running Swift 2.2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`defer` is illegal in an `init` method. The compiler would like to tell you so, but it's crashing before it can do so.

There is a proposal on the table to fix this in an upcoming iteration of Swift 3, and to allow `defer` to work in this context, under certain circumstances, as there are good reasons for doing so; but until then, don't do it.

You will certainly *never* be allowed to call `super` in your `defer`, however, as this would totally defeat the rules for the order in which things must be done during initialization. The particular thing you are trying to do is a terrible idea. The compiler knows the rules for initializing in a safe and consistent fashion; listen to the compiler.